# How can I avoid the segmentation fault in a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, nasm

So, I have a function that prints nCr. The user asks for input from the user, and my function inculcates the recursive function for getting nCr:

```
 int nCr(int n, int r){
    if (r == 0 || r == n){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (nCr(n-1, r-1) + nCr(n-1, r));
    }
 }
```

This is the function I did when I try to convert it into NASM:

```
nCr:
mov ebp, esp
cmp word[ebp + 4], 0
je baseCase
mov ax, word[ebp + 6]
cmp word[ebp + 4], ax
je baseCase

cont:
dec ax
mov bx, word[ebp + 4]
dec bx
sub esp, 2
push ax
push bx
call nCr ;call nCr(n-1, r-1)
pop ax
mov ebp, esp
mov word[ebp + 8], ax
mov ax, 0
sub esp, 2
push ax
push word[ebp + 4]
call nCr ; call nCr(n-1, r)
pop ax
mov ebp, esp
add word[ebp + 8], ax
ret 4

baseCase:
mov word[ebp + 8], 1
ret 4
```

I tested it out with 3 and 2 and I got a segmentation fault (core dumped) error message. Is there something that I need to do or change in this block of code (assume that the inputs are converted into integers from ASCII characters)?

Comment: are you sure it happens in this function?

Comment: I pretty much was. I keep rechecking this block of code. Encountered a bug where I did not update ax before pushing it.

Comment: I assume this is c? It works when I try it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWnhieFI3Rk00QVU